# using theme.spacing inside theme definition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following theme setup:

```
export const themeDefault = createTheme({
  themeName: 'Default (Mortgage Hub)',
  spacing: 4,
  ...typography,
  palette,
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          paddingLeft: theme.spacing(12),
          paddingRight: theme.spacing(4),
          border: '10px',
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

And I would like to use `theme.spacing` inside however, of course. Theme is not defined yet. I have tried to use `makeStyles & useTheme` however these are hooks. So of course they will not work.

Are you able to supply styleOverrides once the theme has been indicated?

Answer (score 0):

The `styleOverrides` feature of the theme is extremely powerful and versatile. In the [Overrides based on props](https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#overrides-based-on-props) portion of the documentation, you can find an example of specifying a callback within the `styleOverrides` which then gives you access to the component's props and state (via `ownerState`) and the theme.

Below is an example showing how the callback syntax gives you access to the theme as well as showing how you can leverage `ownerState` to do conditional styles based on the props passed to a component (e.g. based on whether or not `startIcon` was specified or which `variant` was used or any combination of interest).

```
import * as React from "react";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import SaveIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Save";

const theme = createTheme({
  themeName: "Default (Mortgage Hub)",
  spacing: 4,
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: ({ ownerState, theme }) => {
          const conditionalStyles = {};
          if (ownerState.startIcon !== undefined) {
            conditionalStyles.paddingLeft = theme.spacing(6);
            if (ownerState.variant === "outlined") {
              conditionalStyles.border = "5px solid black";
              conditionalStyles["&:hover"] = { border: "5px solid grey" };
            }
          } else {
            conditionalStyles.paddingLeft = theme.spacing(4);
          }
          return {
            ...conditionalStyles,
            paddingRight: theme.spacing(4)
          };
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
export default function BasicButtons() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
        <Button variant="text">Text</Button>
        <Button variant="contained">Contained</Button>
        <Button variant="outlined">Outlined</Button>
        <Button startIcon={<SaveIcon />} variant="contained">
          Contained with startIcon
        </Button>
        <Button startIcon={<SaveIcon />} variant="outlined">
          Outlined with startIcon
        </Button>
      </Stack>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit BasicButtons Material Demo (forked)]