# MUI Custom Variants not inheriting root styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-glade-tfix6s

I have some custom [variants](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-glade-tfix6s?file=/src/themes/default/form/button/index.js) and I would like these to take the colours from the theme which I have defined on [palette](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-glade-tfix6s?file=/src/themes/default/palette.js).
[image]

I would like my custom variants to have the same styling that is globally set inside the theme to be inherited. However it does not seem to be happening

[image]

```
variants: [
  {
    props: { variant: "icon", size: "large" },
    style: {
      color: "inherit",
      background: "inherit"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you expecting your `icon` variant to have the styling of the `contained` variant? What specific aspects of the styling are you expecting to be different than what is happening?

Comment: In your sandbox you create a theme, but you aren't using it. I would expect `App.js` to wrap everything in `ThemeProvider` specifying your theme, but you aren't using `ThemeProvider` anywhere that I can see.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Ryan. Also sorry I didn't make it clear in the question. I have updated the sandbox to include the ThemeProvider, thanks for pointing that. So I would expect the icon variant to have the same styling that has been applied to `contained` I realise now, this would not be the case as `contained` has its own styling set. However I would have expected... I stand corrected... My thought process was wrong on this :D

Comment: You have taught me well Ryan. I've got an insight into how this works better now. Here is another thing I am still struggling with mind you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71338360/using-theme-spacing-inside-theme-definition