# MUI V5 migration- Transitions.create in createTheme

Tags: material-ui

Currently, the existing codebase has some overrides in the createTheme i.e. :

```js
return createTheme({
  ...
  overrides: {
    MuiChip: {
      deletable: {
        "&:focus": {
            backgroundColor: grey[200],
            "& $deleteIcon": {
              color: primary.dark,
              transition: transitions.create(["color"]),
            },
            "& $deleteIcon:hover": {
              color: darken(primary.dark, 0.2),
              transition: transitions.create(["color"]),
            },
          },
      }
    }
  }
})
```

The transition library was moved away from `import transitions from "@material-ui/core/styles/transitions";`. I can't find the new import that properly matches or the documentation. There is documentation that speaks to using `theme.transition.create` but i'm not clear how that's meant to be used inside of the createTheme method. Is there documentation or a new way to access that method within the the createTheme?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71338360/using-theme-spacing-inside-theme-definition/71357561#71357561) for how to access the theme from within style overrides.

Comment: @RyanCogswell sorry I don't understand how that would apply in my setup/what I would need to change.

Comment: You would use the callback syntax for `deletable` which would give you access to the theme so that you can then use `theme.transitions.create` in the same way that the example in my answer to the other question uses `theme.spacing`.